# Update Each First Occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have these 2 tables:

**Test** (**id**, **suma**) with the following values:
**1,1**
**1,2**
**2,3**
**2,4**
**2,5**
**3,6**
**3,7**
**3,8**
**3,9**

**Payments** (**id**, **amount**) with the following values:
**1, 5**
**1, 7**
**1, 11**
**2, 14**
**2, 3**
**3, 4**
**3, 2**

What I need to do is update the first ocurrence ONLY of each id from the test table with the sum(amount) from the second table based on the id.

So far I have this, but it updates all ocurrences instead of just the first one for each id:

```
UPDATE test SET test.suma = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.id = test.id)
```

If I add **LIMIT 1**, it will only update the first row of the first id. I need it to update the first row of each id (first row of 1, first row of 2, first row of 3)

Comment: Which row in `test` is the "first" one? Is it **`(2,3)`** or **`(2,4)`** or **`(2,5)`**? How do you identify that this particular row is the "first" one?

Answer (score 2):

**Not tested**

Try this code, it will update every row of test where id contains the minimun value of suma only.
Means. It will update only the first column of every different id

```
 UPDATE test SET test.suma = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payments 

 WHERE payments.id = (select test.id from test where suma = (select min(suma) from test)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one assumes you have no multiple `id` **and** `suma` in your table `test`, and that if you do, it's no problem that both are updated.

Also it assumes that the "first" one is the one with lowest `suma`. There is no order in a relational table, unless you specify one with `order by` clause.

```
UPDATE test t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) amount FROM payments GROUP BY id
) p ON p.id = t.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MIN(suma) suma FROM test GROUP BY id
) st ON t.id = st.id AND t.suma = st.suma
SET t.suma = p.amount;
```